# Automatic creation of polygons

Tags: qgis, interpolation, geometric-network

How do you automatically create adjacent polygons in QGIS whose size depends on an attribute of another layer? 
I have a layer with community areas and the corresponding number of inhabitants and would like to automatically create polygons that always contain more or less the same number of inhabitants from the communities.

Below is a picture that hopefully helps to understand my question. I am looking for something similar like a cartogram tool. I want to create polygons of variable size depending on the amount of the attribute "EWZ" in a different layer. The polygons should take the size of polygons of the other layer until the sum of the attribute has a range of 5000 to 10000. 
[image: polygons with size depends on "EWZ"]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing what you want?

Comment: can you give an example (visual diagram) please.